# Recycler View shows identical items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have an arrayList<> of strings and I added 10 strings to it.

```
private val names: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
```

These are the strings added

```
[G.I. Joe: The Rise of Cobra, Creed 2, The Equalizer 2, Ride Along 2, Mission Impossible, Mission Impossible II, Mission Impossible III, Mission Impossible: Ghost Protocol, Mission Impossible: Fallout, Suicide Squad]
```

I have a recycler view with its adapter as follows:

```
class MovieSeriesAdapter(
    private val movie: MoviesInSeries,
    private val movieNameList: ArrayList<String>?,
    private val restMoviesPosition: Int,
    ): RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieSeriesAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(binding: SeriesMoviesItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val mainThing = binding.mainThing
        val tvMovieNameAndYear = binding.seriesMovieNameAndYear

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    return ViewHolder(SeriesMoviesItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent,         false))
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if (position % 2 != 0) {
            holder.mainThing.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8E8E8"))
        }

        val RestMoviesList = Constants.getRestOfSeriesMovies()

        var targetPosition: Int = 0
        when (movie.originalMovieName) {
            "G.I. Joe: Retaliation" -> targetPosition = 0
            "Creed" -> targetPosition = 1
            "The Equalizer" -> targetPosition = 2
            "Ride Along" -> targetPosition = 3
            "Mission Impossible" -> targetPosition = 4
            "Suicide Squad" -> targetPosition = 9
            "Venom" -> targetPosition = 10


        }


        val targetMovieName = movieNameList!![targetPosition]


        holder.tvMovieNameAndYear.text = "$targetMovieName ($targetMovieDate)"
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 5

}
```

The thing is that sometimes I need the recycler view to show 5 items, as in the case below. For Example, I have 5 movies of mission impossible and I want to show them. But the `targetPosition` is an integer variable of only one number.
I tried creating an array list of only the mission impossible movies but it showed identical 5 items with all of the data in one item.
How do I make it that when I need 5 items to be displayed, each item should get a diffent value from the name array list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll recommend you to directly use the value of position for targetValue, inside onBindViewHolder while setting the value of text.

Answer (score 0):

You should just give the adapter a list of the 5 you want to show.

Also, a lot of the code you wrote doesn't make a lot of sense.

For example

```
  when (movie.originalMovieName) {
```

You decide here something based on movie.originalMovieName, but this `movie` is passed in the constructor of the adapter, which already doesn't make sense, but it also means that it will be the same movie for every item.

Comment: So I create a new array of the 5 strings, and then pass it directly with the position?